# Disable check box unchecked option

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Im using check box and I want that If row is type key disable the option 
to unchecked it,how i can do that?

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKey}" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
       <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>-->
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **`IsChecked` to true** and set **`IsEnabled` to false** so that user can't un-check it.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKey}" Value="True">
  <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: HI Rohit - i use data grid and there is no Is checked property ....<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                              
                                <Style.Triggers>

Comment: what i need to do is just grayed out the check box and change it to disable when key is true